# WPF how to bidirectionally link a checkBox to a class member AND to another static variable

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, data-binding, class-members

I have a checkbox which is binded to a class variable in the xaml code:

```
 <CheckBox x:Name="cbxUseBubbleNotifications" Margin="20" IsChecked="{Binding Path=pcdLoggerData.UseBubbleNotifications, Mode=TwoWay}"  Content="_Use bubble notifications"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource CheckboxSwitchStyle}" />
```

this should be supposed to be a two way binding but what happen is:

1. the checkbox is set to CHECKED ----> the var pcdLoggerData.UseBubbleNotifications is automatically OK
2. the class is serialized (through datacontract serialization but I think that doesn't change anything).
3. I restart the program and so the pcdLoggerData.UseBubbleNotifications is automatically set to true
   4 the checkbox is not set to TRUE <----- ERROR

point 4 is not correct: since two way I expect to do that automatically.

My class is:

```
[DataContract]
public class PCDLoggerBinSerializableData
{
  public PCDLoggerBinSerializableData() { }
  public PCDLoggerBinSerializableData(string _languageInUse, bool _useBubbleNotifications)
  {
   LanguageInUse = _languageInUse;
    UseBubbleNotifications = _useBubbleNotifications;
  }
  [DataMember]
  public string LanguageInUse { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public bool UseBubbleNotifications { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Even more important I have to set another variable according to the same value/variations of pcdLogger.UseBubbleNotifications and that is a STATIC var.
something like Bubble.NoBubbles = !pcdmisData.UseBubbleNotifications

So two problems:

1. databinding not TWO-WAY working (only one way)
2. how to databind also another static var?

Thanks

--ADD--

Not working I put breakpoints in all parts of the class and they never were it.

This is how I did it:

```
 [DataContract]
 public class PCDLoggerBinSerializableData: INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
   #region CONSTRUCTORS
   public PCDLoggerBinSerializableData() { }
   public PCDLoggerBinSerializableData(string _languageInUse, bool _useBubbleNotifications)
   {
     LanguageInUse = _languageInUse;
     UseBubbleNotifications = _useBubbleNotifications;
   }
   #endregion

   #region OPTIONS
   [DataMember]
   public string LanguageInUse { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   private bool useBubbleNotifications;
   public bool UseBubbleNotifications
   {
     get { return useBubbleNotifications; }
     set
     {
       useBubbleNotifications = value;
       Bubble.NoBubblesPlease = !useBubbleNotifications;
       OnPropertyChange("UseBubbleNotifications");
     }
   }
   #endregion

   #region NOTIFIER
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   public void OnPropertyChange(string inName)
   {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("inName"));
   }
   #endregion
  }
```

Comment: For your first problem, have you tried using INotifyPropertyChanged? I think you have to do that to let the view know you have updated it in code.

For your second problem, how can you have a checkbox that is bound to two different variables? What if those variables are different? Which value is the checkbox supposed to show? If those values are always going to be the same, then can you just set the second value in the setter of your UseBubbleNotifications setter property?

Comment: No I didn't would you please show me how in an answer? As for the second problem? thanx

Comment: Not sure if that is helpin but I' m getting this error:

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like:

```
public bool UseBubbleNotifications
{
 get
 {
    return useBubbleNotifications;
 }
 set
 {
    useBubbleNotifications = value;
    Other_Static_Variable = value;
    OnPropertyChange("UseBubbleNotifications");
 }
}

public void OnPropertyChange(string inName)
{
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
      {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("inName"));
      }
}
```

Something like this may work. Of course your class would have to inherit the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'pcdLoggerData' value (type 'Object') from '' (type 'MainViewModel'). BindingExpression:Path=pcdLoggerData.UseBubbleNotifications; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=63617293); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name='cbxUseBubbleNotifications'); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1') InvalidOperationException:'System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid Path propertyPercorso della proprietà non valido.

Comment: For 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject+MetaDynamic'  there is not a public property colled 'Items'.
   in CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   in System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   in MS.Internal.DynamicPropertyAccessorImpl.GetValue(Object component)
   in MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)
   in MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)'

Comment: What is your data context set to?